# Inaccurate Result from using QGIS contour function on pgr_driving distance

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I was wondering whether anybody else has experienced a similar problem when using the contour function in QGIS.

I've run PGRouting's pgr_drivingdistance function on some osm data, and applied the contour function to this, although this has produced an inaccurate output[image]

I've used the clip function to clip the sections of highway that fall within this contour as shown below, however this is consequently inaccurate because of the the contouring. [image]

Does anybody know of any solutions to this problem?

---

I'm using the contour plugin in QGIS, and these are my settings. I've played around with these settings but it doesn't seem to make any real difference to the outputs which I'm getting.

[image]

Comment: Which contour algorithm do you use and what are the settings?